# `$http:badreq Bad Request Configuration` - from angular post method, what is wrong here?

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

I am developing sample app to learn the `angularjs` using `node.js`. when i post the data to backend to create a new `family` i am getting error as :

```
Error: $http:badreq
Bad Request Configuration
Http request configuration url must be a string.  Received: 
{
    "method":"POST",
    "url":"api/family",
    "data":  {
                "username":"fagruddin",
                "password":"valaanur",
                "familyLeader":"fagruddin",
                "husband":"fagruddin",
                "wife":"rejiya",
                "child":2
     },
     "headers":{
         "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
     }
}
```

what is wrong here? any one help me to solve this?

[Live Demo for your reference](https://ide.c9.io/a3gwebtrain/myfamily)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using the shortcut post method, you omit the configuration parameter making the first parameter the url.

Since you passed in a configuration object instead of the url as the first parameter, you are getting the error.

```
$http.post(
  '/api/family', 
  vm.form, 
  {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-formurlencoded'}}
).success(function(data) {
    console.log( 'data', data );
})
```

if you are using the straight http, then you can pass config object :

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'api/family',
    data : vm.form,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
}).success(function(data) {
    console.log( 'data', data );
})
```

Comment: I am using the second approach right? then why I am getting error?

Comment: nope, you are using the post shortcut. Your call looks like $http.post

Comment: updated, but getting this error : `angular.js:12011 POST https://myfamily-a3gwebtrain.c9users.io/api/family 500 (Internal Server Error)` - but when i use `postman` it works

Comment: It looks like an issue with your node endpoint. You should post it in a separate question since its a different error.

Comment: Also it looks like the data is not being form url encoded judging by the error. Have you tried letting it go through as json? Is your node endpoint setup to handle json? If not, i would probably set it up and use json unless there is a good reason to stick to form url encoding